# Escaping ampersand character in SQL string

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, sqlplus

I am trying to query a certain row by name in my sql database and it has an ampersand. I tried to set an escape character and then escape the ampersand, but for some reason this isn't working and I'm uncertain as to what exactly my problem is.

```
Set escape '\'
    select * from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_id in(
    select node2_id from V1144engine.T_edges where node1_id in(
    select node2_id from V1144engine.T_edges where node1_id in(
    select node2_id from V1144engine.T_edges where node1_id = 
      (select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'Geometric Vectors \& Matrices')))
    and edge_type_id = 1)
    and node_type_id = 1
    and node_id in (
    select node2_id from V1144engine.T_edges where node1_id =
      (select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'Algebra II')
    and edge_type_id = 2);
```

Comment: i don't think you need the quote around the escape ('\') character

Comment: `set define off` is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Instead of

```
node_name = 'Geometric Vectors \& Matrices'
```

use

```
node_name = 'Geometric Vectors ' || chr(38) || ' Matrices'
```

38 is the ascii code for ampersand, and in this form it will be interpreted as a string, nothing else. I tried it and it worked.

Another way could be using LIKE and an underline instead the '&' character:

```
node_name LIKE 'Geometric Vectors _ Matrices'
```

The chance that you'll find some other record too, which is different in only this one character, is quite low.

Comment: Instead of the unintuitive `chr(38)`, you can do `node_name = 'Geometric Vectors &' || ' Matrices'`

Comment: For other poor confused souls alike to myself, note that it is `chr(38)`, *not* `char(38)`.

Comment: Note that `&` doesn't need to be escaped in MySQL. Also MySQL doesn't have the function `CHR()`.

Answer (score 140):

[Escape is set to `\` by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#BGBFAHDB), so you don't need to set it; but if you do, don't wrap it in quotes.

Ampersand is the SQL*Plus [substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453) marker; but you can [change it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698854), or more usefully in your case turn it off completely, with:

```
set define off
```

Then you don't need to bother escaping the value at all.

Comment: The escape *character* is set to `\ ` by default, but the boolean parameter `escape` is set to OFF by default. So the OP may not need to set the escape character, but he/she needs to at least `SET ESCAPE ON` for that to work. Or, of course, use any of the other, better solutions.

Answer (score 53):

You can use

```
set define off
```

Using this it won't prompt for the input

Answer (score 38):

straight from oracle sql fundamentals book

```
SET DEFINE OFF
select 'Coda & Sid' from dual;
SET DEFINE ON
```

how would one escape it without setting define.

Comment: The addition of SET DEFINE ON is helpful.

Comment: @Roman Without define you could use as well: select 'Coda ''&'' Sid' from dual; (double single quotes)

Answer (score 16):

In order to escape `&` you can try following ways:-

1. `set scan off`
2. `set define off`
3. `set escape on`
   then replace `&` by`\&`
4. replace `&` by `&&`

One of them should work at least.

*additionally if you are using PL/SQL developer then there is & **icon** in the bottom of SQL window please go there and **disable** it*. Note in the older version this option is not present.

*Also make sure set define off is written at the very beginning of the script.*

Comment: In step 3, shouldn’t that be `\&` ?

Comment: updated answer @Manngo

Answer (score 4):

```
set escape on
... node_name = 'Geometric Vectors \& Matrices' ...
```

or alternatively:

```
set define off
... node_name = 'Geometric Vectors & Matrices' ...
```

The first allows you to use the backslash to escape the &.

The second turns off & "globally" (no need to add a backslash anywhere). You can turn it on again by `set define on` and from that line on the ampersands will get their special meaning back, so you can turn it off for some parts of the script and not for others.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

`select * from mde_product where cfn = 'A3D"&"R01'`

you define `&` as literal by enclosing is with double qoutes `"&"` in the string.

Comment: If you do that, the the double-quotes will become part of the string, like this: `A3D"&"R01`

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(<your xml column>,'&',chr(38)||'amp;')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a regex to help find and replace "&" within an INSERT, I hope that this helps someone.

The trick was to make sure that the "&" was with other text.

Find `“(\'[^\']*(?=\&))(\&)([^\']*\')”`

Replace `“$1' || chr(38) || '$3”`

Answer (score 0):

```
--SUBSTITUTION VARIABLES
-- these variables are used to store values TEMPorarily.
-- The values can be stored temporarily through
-- Single Ampersand (&)
-- Double Ampersand(&&)
-- The single ampersand substitution variable applies for each instance when the
--SQL statement is created or executed.
-- The double ampersand substitution variable is applied for all instances until
--that SQL statement is existing.
INSERT INTO Student (Stud_id, First_Name, Last_Name, Dob, Fees, Gender)
VALUES (&stud_Id, '&First_Name' ,'&Last_Name', '&Dob', &fees, '&Gender');
--Using double ampersand substitution variable
INSERT INTO Student (Stud_id,First_Name, Last_Name,Dob,Fees,Gender)
VALUES (&stud_Id, '&First_Name' ,'&Last_Name', '&Dob', &&fees,'&gender');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

I know it sucks. None of the above things were really working, but I found a work around. Please be extra careful to use spaces between the apostrophes [ ' ], otherwise it will get escaped.

```
SELECT 'Hello ' '&' ' World';

Hello & World
```

You're welcome ;)