# Query by the string containing &

Tags: string, sharepoint

I have got a string containing "&" like "Coke & Cola" How to use this string on Queries with & Please Help me.

I must Query by this sign &

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string there is a answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

> amp;

or

> \&

?

I'm making the assumption that you're using Sharepoint given the tag - I found an article here that might be relevant to your problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/90479143-e26e-45cc-ae56-16574056d6d4

Answer (score 0):

[general **SQL**] There are many answers take a look at source link:

```
SET ESCAPE ON
SET ESCAPE ""
SELECT 'You & me' FROM DUAL;
```

**[source](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#How_does_one_disable_interactive_prompting_in_SQL.2APlus.3F)**

[**CAML SharePoint**] answer:
replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: oh, sorry didn't see tags in there, consider my answer as "general one". For you this is the solution: replace `&` with `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

`&` must be changed to `&amp;`

Also `<`must be changed to `&lt;` and `>`must be changed to `&gt;`