# Django Haystack-Xapian search fails with special characters and spaces

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-haystack, xapian

I'm working on an existing Django project which uses haystack with xapian backend for a global search feature. However the search seems to fail while I search with some special characters like & and spaces etc. I tried but could not find out a way to fix it.

Is there a way I can escape these characters and make the search work? I'm using PostgreSQL at the back-end. Any pointers will be very helpful.

**Update:** Search feature uses a SearchForm and the query string comes in q field of the from. This is used as below in the code.

```
sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])
```

I've tried using:

```
sqs = self.searchqueryset.filter(self.cleaned_data['q'])
```

and

```
sqs = self.searchqueryset.filter(content=Clean(self.cleaned_data['q']))
```

with no luck. I'm still not able to search with spaces and special characters like &.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string

Comment: Can you show what error message you get?

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson I'm not getting any error messages. It's just that I'm not getting any results while I'm searching with special characters like '&' in my search string. It works otherwise.

Comment: Have you managed to run the SQL query and get results (without django that is)?

Answer (score 1):

Escaping depends on how you are using Haystack, however, the `haystack.inputs.Clean` class may be what you are looking for. Just pass in whatever you are searching for:

```
q = "amp & sand"
q_clean = haystack.inputs.Clean(q)
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=q_clean)
```

See the docs here: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/inputtypes.html#clean

Comment: I've already tried it, but it is still not fetching the data as per the query result if there are special characters like '&' in the search string.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the (new) maintainer of Xapian-Haystack.

I believe that what you are reporting is related with how Xapian-Haystack parses the string into indexable terms for searching: because it uses Xapian default generator, which ignores special characters, you are unable to search special characters because they are not even indexed.

For instance, the string `"^ best-seller"` is indexed as: `"best"` and `"seller"`: an search on `"^"` or an exact search on `"^ best-seller"` will fail.

[This has been solved for now](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/commit/fc0a9f71d23284927cdb39d6d0afa27de0b2877a): all special characters should now be supported.

Space is never indexed because in Xapian-Haystack (or Haystack) since it is the word separator.

While I wouldn't recommend using master on production at the moment, maybe this answers your question.

Comment: yeah I understand that spaces are not indexed and that makes sense. However, searching the special characters was important in my case. After trying and spending a good amount of time, I had to replace xapian with another search engine :(