# How to escape & character in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ENTRY_GUID FROM 
       (SELECT e.ENTRY_GUID FROM alertwlnqedv3.ENTRY e,
                                 alertwlnqedv3.ENTRY_PARTNERDEFINED_INFO ep,
                                 alertwlnqedv3.PRODUCT p
        WHERE e.ENTRY_GUID = ep.ENTRY_GUID AND 
              e.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE AND
             (XMLEXISTS('/partnerDefinedInfo/facetedIds/alertGroup[text()=
             ("Colleen&s Main Web2 QA Folder")]' PASSING PARTNERDEFINED_INFO) ) AND 
              e.STATUS_CODE != 13 AND 
              p.PRODUCT_VALUE =1)
```

Am trying to run the above query - where `Colleen&s Main Web2 QA Folder` is the text entered on a run time. Now as it allows the special character `&` the query is breaking. I tried to escape with \ and one more `&` but still it fails. Please let me know how can I handle this scenario. TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping ampersand character in SQL string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string)

Comment: No luck with this too.....Getting error "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Can you confirm that when you take out the & that it works?

Comment: Yes, it works when I take out &.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `chr(38)` instead of `&`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ENTRY_GUID FROM 
       (SELECT e.ENTRY_GUID FROM alertwlnqedv3.ENTRY e,
                                 alertwlnqedv3.ENTRY_PARTNERDEFINED_INFO ep,
                                 alertwlnqedv3.PRODUCT p
        WHERE e.ENTRY_GUID = ep.ENTRY_GUID AND 
              e.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE AND
             (XMLEXISTS(('/partnerDefinedInfo/facetedIds/alertGroup[text()=
             ("Colleen'||chr(38)||'s Main Web2 QA Folder")]') PASSING PARTNERDEFINED_INFO) ) AND 
              e.STATUS_CODE != 13 AND 
              p.PRODUCT_VALUE =1)
```

Comment: this is also trowing error "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: try to enclose the entire string/xml with `()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this pattern:

`'text1&' || 'text2'`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using that value inside an XPath expression, you need to escape the ampersand using an XML entity. So you need to replace every `&` in your input string with `&amp;`

You also need to take care of other special XML characters:

- `&` - `&amp;`
- `<` - `&lt;`
- `>` - `&gt;`
- `"` - `&quot;`
- `'` - `&apos;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate little bit? I tried replacing & by &amp; but Oracle is prompting me to enter a value for AMP.

Comment: @RajeshBhat: it's not "Oracle" that prompts for a variable, it's SQL*Plus: http://stackoverflow.com/q/118190/330315

Comment: Oh ohk, am running the query in SQLDeveloper. So how can I stop that? I need to run the query from java application too.

Comment: @RajeshBhat: I don't use SQL Developer but I think `set define off`should also work. You need to read the manual. This is a client application thing, so your Java application won't be affected

Comment: @RajeshBhat I can confirm `set define off` works also in Oracle SQLDeveloper (I had to use it just last week). There might also be a SQLDeveloper specific configuration option for the same thing.

Comment: after running set define off it started throwing error without any prompt. Error is : ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation:  
ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_XQUERYINT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
19112. 00000 -  "error raised during evaluation: %s"
*Cause:    The error function was called during evaluation of the XQuery expression.
*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.