# Is there a way to search string literals in SQL on Oracle that ignores the ampersand &?

Tags: string, oracle, sqlplus, literals

I am querying an Oracle database using SQL developer.

When searching a string that contains the ampersand in SQL, I currently have to run the command "set define off;" preceding the query in order for it to not be treated as a 'define' variable.

For example:

```
set define off;
select 'Dungeons&Dragons' from dual;
set define on;
```

Works as expected and the '&' is treated as a literal character. But I wonder if there was a way to do this by marking the string as a literal such as:

```
select l'Dungeons&Dragons' from dual;
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: I think that's the best way to do it. You could use an escape character ('\'), e.g. 'Dungeons\&Dragons', but that doesn't seem worth the trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string

Comment: For another alternative, see second option in answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/118210/121544

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ignore ampersands in a SQL script running from SQL Plus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus)

Comment: @VivekChavda, Escaping like that does not work in SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Use a login.sql script with `SET DEFINE OFF` on sql developer startup. Go to Tools-Preferences-Database and on Filename for connection startup script select the new login.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the prompt character to a different character too:

```
SET DEFINE '^'
```

Then issue your query like normal.