# Query using Oracle substitution variables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a example SQL code like below

```
select *
  from Engg_Studens
 where Student_Name = '&Student_Name'
   And Department = 'computer science & Engineering' ;
```

My question here is: while running the SQL, it is asking for the substitution variable for `'& engineering'`  which is in department name. 
I should only be asked for `'&student_name'`.

Comment: This happens because you have not properly escaped the `&` in `'computer science & Engineering'` and that it consider it as a bind variable. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string) for solutions

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but that is a substitution variable, not a bind parameter. They are different things.

Comment: I suggested the question title change to "Query using Oracle substitution variables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the second ampersand (`&`) but honestly I never remember how to do that off the top of my head. I usually do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM engg_studens
 WHERE student_Name = '&Student_Name'
   AND department = 'Computer Science &' || ' Engineering';
```

Using the concatenation (`||`) operator here avoids the replacement variable.

Comment: tried with the syntax , and it worked . thanks for the script .

Answer (score 3):

You can not write a statement which includes the "&"  character.

Try like below:

```
select * from Engg_Studens where Student_Name = '&Student_Name' 
and Department = 'computer science '|| chr(38) ||' Engineering' ;
```

Comment: Actually you can. You would either have to escape the character properly, change the setting for substitution variables character (to use a different character) or turn off the substitution variables at all (and use parameterized queries instead).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to [change the substitution character](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073) to something you are sure will not be used elsewhere:

```
SQL> set define ^

SQ> select *
  from Engg_Studens
 where Student_Name = '^Student_Name'
   And Department = 'computer science & Engineering'

Enter value for student_name: Arif
old   3:  where Student_Name = '^Student_Name'
new   3:  where Student_Name = 'Arif'
```

Only the `^Student_Name` is now treated as a substitution variable so you only get a prompt for that.

You could also potentially separate the prompt from the query and switch to using an actual bind variable, but that seems like overkill here.

Comment: It worked when I tested it so not sure what to tell you. Depends what "did not work" means.