# oracle - ampersand in json path

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I have json data in which there is ampersand in the json path. how do I esacpe ampersand. I have tried these things but nothing is working -
1) set define off
2) escape ampersand - \&
3) using double ampersand - &&

```
SELECT id,array1
FROM   (
  select '{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "array1 & tr": "TEST",
      }
    ]
  }' AS JSON_DATA
  FROM DUAL
) I,
json_table(
  i.JSON_DATA ,
  '$.data[*]'  
  COLUMNS (
    array1 varchar2(4000) FORMAT JSON path'$."array1 & tr"',
    ID     varchar2(4000) path '$."id"'
  )  
) a
```

> **ORA-40442:** JSON path expression syntax error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string)

Comment: No problem exists [in fiddle for version 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e4e46e7ec58152691b718ba847abf20) , I also tried within version 12.1.0.2. Are you sure about the sample in the question ?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barbaros. No, its not working for me in oracle 12c. I have done a workaround, have replaced '&' with 'and'.

Comment: Thanks  @Dortimer for the help, I have replace '&' with 'and'

Answer (score 2):

From the Oracle docs:

Put the "&" between braces {}

(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm)

From another answer:

Use ASCII equivalent of ampersand to be sure it's interpreted as string

```
 "array1 " || chr(38) || " tr": "TEST",
```

[Escaping ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string)

I am not able to test it at the moment, but i found those answers matching your case.

Comment: The `{}` thing is for Oracle Text. Don't know if it works in the database.

Comment: This give the error " JSON path expression syntax error ('$."FOO " || chr(38) || " BAR"')
JZN-00209: Unexpected characters after end of path"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this; note the use of the unicode \u0026 instead of chr(38): ,"FOO_AND_BAR" path '$."FOO \u0026 BAR"'