# Maximo map identify tool: Add a hyperlink?

Tags: arcgis-js-api, maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5

I have URLs in my GIS layers in Maximo Spatial:

[image]

Is there a way to display a URL as a hyperlink so that a user can open it in a new tab/window in the browser?

*(Or invoke a URL REST request on the server-side -- whatever applies.)*

<sup>*Keyword: Maximo Spatial*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use HTML in the URL.

- The webpage opens in a new tab in Google Chrome (which is good).

`<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=43.000000,-78.000000'> Link </a>`

[image]

---

The SQL behind this is:

```
'<a href=''http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' ||chr(38)|| 'layer=c' ||chr(38)|| 
    'cbll=43.000000,-78.000000''> Link </a>' as description,
```

> Hint:
>
> In Toad, the ampersand was being interpreted as a variable.  I had to escape/replace the ampersand with `||chr(38)||` .
>
> More info here: [Escaping ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961550/10936066)