# How to fix a where clause in which a string has an Ampersand in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL developer and stuck in the following part of my query

```
   WHERE table.books IN ('Jekyll & Hyde','Power')
```

The ampersand in `"Jekyll & Hyde"` is causing a window asking to enter a value, how can I fix the syntax so that it recognizes this as one of the titles I am looking to filter by.

looking to retrieve readers that have read certain titles, but the query is not executing in its current state

Comment: Asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

before running the query; it'll *instruct* SQL Developer not to ask for a value of the substitution variable.