How to query special character '&' in Oracle?
I tried below query in Oracle, and it keeps on coming up and Input box with 'Enter Value for:'. Even though when it's changed to '%Hair & Beauty%', it still has the same issue. Any suggestions? Thanks
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE
Product_type LIKE '%Hair & Beauty%'
Any suggestions Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string
